# when "Not complete" is selected from a listbox i want 0 to be entered into a textbox

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox, selecteditem

I have a listbox with an item called "Not complete" I want 0 to be entered into a textbox when this is selected is that possible?

```
    If CoreUnit1ComboBx.SelectedItem = Nothing Or CoreUnit1CSComBx.SelectedItem = Nothing Or CoreUnit1TxtBx.Text = "" Then
    ElseIf CoreUnit1CSComBx.SelectedItem = "Not Complete" Then
        CoreUnit1Total = 0
        CoreUnit1TxtBx.Text = "0" 

    Else
        CoreUnit1Total = CoreUnit1CSComBx.SelectedItem * CoreUnit1TxtBx.Text
    End If
```

Comment: and what is wrong with the current code? are you getting any error

Comment: After "not complete" is selected 0 doesn't appear in my textbox my teacher said I have to use a button but I wanted 0 to appear in the textbox as soon as it is selected

Comment: Where do you run this code? Is it in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler? And by the way, your teacher has nothing to say about multiplying a string with and object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There many ways to do this, however the `case statement` is probably the best and in the long run is much cleaner than using the `if statement`.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem
        Case Is = "Not Completed"
            TextBox1.Text = "0"
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Not Completed")
End Sub
End Class
```

If you have any trouble let me know, as mentioned above there is more than one way to achieve what you are wanting to accomplish.

 Happy Coding!

Comment: That's cool I didn't know you could do that I'm going to check out how case statements  work any useful sites?

Comment: stackoverflow :) or https://www.facebook.com/codingwithandrew/videos/561443374023719/